# How does my phone not set on fire?

Tags: batteries, current

My phone has a battery that supposedly contains around 3000mAh. It's also horribly hungry, and when in heavy use can easily eat the battery in under 3 hours. My question is about the fact that discharging a 3000mAh battery in 3 hours means sourcing a current of 1A continuously for that period of time. 1A is enough to melt wires considerably thicker than those on the circuitboard inside my phone. Why is my phone still working?

Comment: The 1 A will be distributed among the sub-circuits, so there is no need for wide traces except maybe around the battery connector/charger/power-supply part. But there, I am sure the traces are wide/thick enough.

Comment: You do not seem to be considering that the "1A" is split up between thousands of different connections. EDIT: Darn it @BenceKaulics , you beat me to the punch!

Comment: One amp at around 4 volts is four watts.  You yourself convert about 100 watts to heat, ie, 25 times as much.  Why aren't you on fire?  The answer is basically the same.

Comment: We tried building a fuse out of a PCB trace, we used 150µm wide trace (35µm thick afair) and formed a structure to increase the heat in the middle. That thing took around 4A to finally get on fire...

Comment: @Arsenal - But I bet the copper/substrate adhesive failed much earlier.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast sure did, but the main function of a fuse was not really achieved, should have failed much earlier but didn't - but the surge pulse destroyed it immediately. Exact the opposite behavior we wanted :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "1A is enough to melt wires considerably thicker than those on the circuitboard inside my phone."

Are you sure?

In any case, the circuitboard wires are flat, short, and all thermally conducive to the board. Heat generated does not stay in a wire but is distributed throughout the phone and case. You'll notice the whole phone gets warm.

[Discussion of required trace width factors at EEVBlog.](http://www.eevblog.com/forum/beginners/pcb-copper-trace-width-for-1a/)